# Organizing common functions/classes

Tags: 6

Currently I have a common.module for storing common functions.  This file is getting way to long and I'd like to start breaking it up by similar functionality or by class:

```
common.inc
common.query.inc
common.taxonomy.inc
Node.php
etc...
```

I thought I could add `files[]` entries to my common.info file but this doesn't seem to source these files.

I need these files to be always sourced: on any page load, on full drupal bootstrap, and on update.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.module` file add the following to the very top of the module (just after the opening `<?php` tag):

```
module_load_include('inc', 'common', 'common.query');
module_load_include('inc', 'common', 'common.taxonomy');
```

For your reference:

[`module_load_include();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/6)

**EDIT**

Seeing as how you're not going to be needing these on cached pages, then putting them in `hook_init()` is much better practice.

Like the following:

```
function common_init() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'common', 'common.query');
  module_load_include('inc', 'common', 'common.taxonomy');
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want that .inc on the end of the file name.

Comment: how does this differ from doing it within `hook_init`()?

Comment: @Andy d'oh - I copied and pasted from the question :p

Comment: @ack You wanted them to be available EVERYWHERE.  This should allow that.  You could implement `hook_init()`, but your files may not always be included.  For example, `hook_init()` does not run on cached pages.

Comment: Well, I'll have to think this through more ... but if that's really the only difference -- this is common helper and library code.  And if a page is cached it shouldn't be running through my module code anyway, and thus cached pages shouldn't require any of these includes.

Comment: If no cached pages are going to be requiring your functions, then yes...put them in `hook_init()` for sure.

Answer (score -1):

You can split out class definitions into separate files and then use `files[]` to cache those class definitions. That's [what files[] does](http://drupal.org/node/542202).

On top of that you could have a common.module file that minimally implements `hook_help()`, and would `require_once()` all the files you want. This is of course not the best way to go; consumers should require_once() the files on their own, for only the files they need.

Also if you're trying to use an external library, you might consider taking a look at the [Libraries module](http://drupal.org/project/libraries).

EDIT: Uh, didn't see that it was tagged 6. :-) Drupal 6 doesn't support `files[]` in the .info file at all.